# How do I convert a MegaParsec "ParseErrorBundle" into a list of "SourcePos" and error messages

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

Using the [MegaParsec `parse` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:parse), I'm able to run a parser, and get a [`ParseErrorBundle` if it fails](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Error.html#t:ParseErrorBundle).

I know that I'm able to pretty print the `ParseErrorBundle`, and get an error message for the entire parse failure, which will include the line and character numbers, using [`errorBundlePretty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Error.html#v:errorBundlePretty).

I also know that I'm able to get a [list of `ParseError`'s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Error.html#t:ParseError) from a `ParseErrorBundle`, using `bundleErrors`. And that I can pretty print these with either `parseErrorPretty` or `parseErrorTextPretty`.

I want to be able to run a parser, and if it fails, get a list of `(SourcePos, Text)`, so that I know both the individual error messages, and the location of each error.
I can't figure out an elegant way to do this. While I could in theory crib fairly heavily from the [source code to `errorBundlePretty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.2.0/docs/src/Text.Megaparsec.Error.html#errorBundlePretty), I feel like folding over the errors and using `reachOffset` to advance the `PosState` can't be the easiest way to go about this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, if you're using `megaparsec >= 7.0.0`, I think you're supposed to use `attachSourcePos` for the traversal.  It returns a `NonEmpty` of `(ParseError, SourcePos)` pairs.  I think it would look like:

```
import qualified Text.Megaparsec as MP
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty (..))
import Data.Void

annotateErrorBundle :: MP.ParseErrorBundle T.Text Void -> NonEmpty (MP.SourcePos, T.Text)
annotateErrorBundle bundle
  = fmap (\(err, pos) -> (pos, T.pack . MP.parseErrorTextPretty $ err)) . fst $
    MP.attachSourcePos MP.errorOffset
                       (MP.bundleErrors bundle)
                       (MP.bundlePosState bundle)
```

Note that unlike your proposed answer, `attachSourcePos` threads the `PosState` properly through the traversal of the error bundle, rather than throwing the updated state away after every `reachOffset` call.  As a result, I believe it will be more efficient for a large number of errors. (It also uses `reachOffsetNoLine` instead of `reachOffset` which may be more efficient for certain stream types.

If you're using a `megaparsec < 7.0.0`, you might want to try to adapt the source for `attachSourcePos` from later versions.

Comment: Thanks, this seems much more reasonable than my answer! not sure how I failed to spot `attachSourcePos`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work as follows:

```hs
import qualified Text.Megaparsec as MP
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty (..))
import qualified Data.Text as T

annotateErrorBundle :: MP.ParseErrorBundle Text Void -> NonEmpty (MP.SourcePos, Text)
annotateErrorBundle bundle = (\e -> (errorSrcPos e, T.pack $ MP.parseErrorTextPretty e)) <$> MP.bundleErrors bundle
  where 
    initialPosState = MP.bundlePosState bundle
    errors = MP.bundleErrors bundle
    errorSrcPos e = MP.pstateSourcePos . snd $ MP.reachOffset (MP.errorOffset e) initialPosState
```

I suspect that this probably isn't super efficient, because I'm calling `reachOffset` once per error. However, in practice, the list of errors probably isn't that large, so I'm not too worried.